# delete data from influxdb 2.0

Tags: influxdb

I want to delete data from influxdb v2.0:
I read its doc and I try 2 ways that it says, but I get error.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/write-data/delete-data/

in cli:

```
influx delete \
--host HOST \
--org ORG \
--token TOKEN \
--bucket BUCKET \
--start 2021-06-01T00:00:00Z \
--stop 2021-06-01T01:00:00Z
```

error:

```
Error: Failed to delete data: Not implemented.
See 'influx delete -h' for help
```

Can you help me, how can I delete data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete data from same host:

```
influx delete --bucket example-bucket \
  --start 2020-03-01T00:00:00Z \
  --stop 2020-11-14T00:00:00Z
```

You can also delete data via Curl

```
curl --request POST https://influxurl/api/v2/delete?org=example-org&bucket=example-bucket \
  --header 'Authorization: Token YOUR_API_TOKEN' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "start": "2022-01-19T06:32:00Z",
    "stop": "2022-01-19T06:33:00Z",
    "predicate": "_measurement=\"example-measurement\" AND feature=\"temp2\" "
  }'
```

Predicate method not working properly. (bug)

Answer (score 0):

For local CLI in docker container.
I had multiple measurements in one bucket, so to delete only them using predicate is necessary. I 've put one day before the first measurement in start and one day after last measurment in stop

```
influx delete --bucket home \
    --start 2021-04-01T00:00:00Z \
    --stop 2023-01-12T00:00:00Z \
    --predicate '_measurement="personal_rating6"'
```